# Java tool to modify test code

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

I read a while ago a post on a French blog about some Java tool that changes the unit test code (like inverting conditions etc) to check that the tests fail quickly.

My problem is I just cannot remember the name right now. Does anybody know it?

Comment: Curious as well, because it kinda rings a bell for me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be [Jumble](http://jumble.sourceforge.net/) you're thinking of.

Comment: Hmmm, indeed, this really looks like it :)
Not maintained since 2009, tho :(

Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 4):

[Jester](http://jester.sourceforge.net/) also fits the description - except that (just like Jumble) it changes the code under test rather than the test code.